# Wait till UITableview finish reloading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

How can we check for UITableView finishes reloading..

Actually I want to call other function after successfully reload UITableView, using this
`[tableview reloadData]` we can't do this.. I had write this code

`[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`

Please help me to solve this problem..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading of `tableView` takes place in other threads. Refer this for hack to achieve this:
[Show tableView popover as soon as data is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750253/show-tableview-popover-as-soon-as-data-is-loaded)

Comment: Thanks dear...but I think this should be not the convenient answer as caling method after 1 second delay..

Comment: True. but i couldnt think of any other workaround :/ there is a private struct, _tableviewflags. Which gives the info required. But not sure how we can access it